# C++ how to make a class type more general and use it as a kind of interface

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, types

I have a class called "OpenGLCamera" 
and there is another class that needs a camera so at the moment he has OpenGLCamera (since the class is used as a type)
like so:

```
void draw(const OpenGLCamera& camera);
```

But i want it to be more general, so i want it to be

```
void draw(const SomeCamera& camera);
```

and this "SomeCamera" should be a pointer/reference or something to OpenGLCamera ofcourse!

I have a class called "Visual_settings".. and i heared i should use inheritance to achieve this... but i dont understand how.. how to do this? in the class Visual_Settings? Make it a base class of... and then??

**Visual_Settings.h**

```
#include "OpenGLCamera.h"
class Visual_Settings : public OpenGLCamera
{

};
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic type that you are looking for which is `SomeCamera`, then `OpenGLCamera` should derive from this type `SomeCamera`. If you cannot do that then you need to use Adapter pattern. This would make sense if you have other types of cameras.

```
    class SomeCamera
    {
    public:
        virtual void Dowork()=0;
    };

    class OpenGLCamera : public SomeCamera
    {
    public:
        virtual void Dowork() override
        {
            //use camera
        }
    };
```

//Approach 2 (bridge pattern): when you cannot modify OpenGLCamera:

//***Use proper constructors/destructors and initialize base class constructors as required

```
    class SomeCamera
    {
    public:
        virtual void Dowork()=0;
    };

    class OpenGLCamera 
    {
    public:
       void OpenGlDowork() 
        {
            //use camera
        }
    };

    class OpenGLCameraAdapter : public SomeCamera, OpenGLCamera
    {
    public:
        virtual void Dowork() override
        {
            //use camera
            OpenGlDowork();

    }
};
```

Comment: Oke i will use that first approach indeed! And how to make the constructor from OpenGLCamera virtual? Since i can't change that name right...?
Or should i just make a virtual constructor "SomeCamera"? and a virtual "OpenGLCamera" and will it see that it should be linked from one to the other?

Comment: The constructor is not virtual the interface is pure virtual. Also destructor should be virtual. I say use proper constructor as per your need i.e. for initialization. I have not shown, constructors and destructors assuming you will have them as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

1. `OpenGLCamera` should be inherited from `SomeCamera`.
2. `SomeCamera` should have interface, that will be overriden in `OpenGLCamera`.